# Where and how do I use the word "apparently"?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Does this word "apparently" mean that something is obvious or does it refer to something that seems true but actually isn't. `Apparent` means illusion, right?

People use this word quite often and I think they misuse it. For example, if a person says like:

> Apparently, I cannot be responsible for all the things.

Does 'apparently' means obviously here? If it does, it's the wrong usage of this word.

Comment: You may use it as an adverb in any sentence that you might also use as a complement to _It appears (to me) that_. Where you put it in the sentence is, like all adverb placement, up to you.

Comment: Since things are sometimes as they appear and sometimes not, it follows that the adverb *apparently* neither reliably confirms nor reliably denies the objective truth of the proposition that it modifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence:

> Apparently, I cannot be responsible for all the things.

It sounds like a rejoinder in an argument, where it is equivalent to

Apparently, you think that I cannot be responsible for all the things.

As far as a lot of people using *apparently* to mean *obviously,* well it might be different from an established meaning, but it could also indicate a change in meaning. A/the meaning of a word is ultimately what people say it is. I may not like that a lot of people use *literally* to 'mean' *figuratively* in a sentence such as

? The kids were literally bouncing off the ceiling today.

But people do, and meanings change.